# Restart installer on any error (PXE with cobbler)

Tags: installation, maas, pxe, kickstart

I provision few boxes using PXE with Cobbler. My network is not very stable, so sometimes the installation fails. The installer is not able to retrieve a package.

Is it possible to make the installer to reboot on any error? I don't want to waste time and go to the machine, connect a keyboard just to press ENTER.

I want my machines to keep rebooting till they are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a configuration to your Cobbler template that adds some feedback to your Cobbler server once installation is complete, or at least reaches a suitable point. Then use that to control an IP mains power control device. If the feedback is not received in a suitable time, cycle the power and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server's PXE deployment tool is MAAS, depending on the version of Ubuntu you re using, Cobbler may not even be a supported component.